# Use indexed redis session with spring cloud api gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, spring-data-redis

I am using [cloud api gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/) with [redis session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/guides/boot-redis.html). It is possible to switch repository-type for this session to **indexed** one to be able to query sessions using `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` by principal name.

I've tried to set this parameter below, but seems it does not work:

```
spring:       
   session:
      redis:
         repository-type: indexed
```

Please clarify if such scenario is supported, I can see that following class `ReactiveRedisIndexedSessionRepository` is not available.